# Does openstreetmap data contain English names for all of Europe?

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm using OSM data from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html, and especially focused on areas around Ukraine. I'm creating mbtiles from the pbf downloads (using tilemaker) and using a tileserver (tileserver-gl) to send vector tiles to the browser.

All works as expected, but for Ukraine and most surrounding countries, i can't figure out how to update my vector styles (styles.json) to render the English name for the country, state, and city. I've tried using 'name:en' in `layers[x].layout.text-field` in my styles, but the tiles then don't render with a name at all, so i assume that tag is missing.

I'm exported an area in Ukraine from the OSM website, just to confirm that 'name:en' is used, at least for some places - altho i can't confirm this for the city, state, country because the export tool says the area is too large to download.

I'm wondering if it's possible that the pbf data doesn't contain the English names.

Does anyone know how to show English names, like I'm trying to do?

Comment: Please focus on one specific question only. No, OSM doesn't contain English names for all places in Europe. However, for most larger cities there will be a `name:en` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it is possible that the pbf data does not contain the English names.

You can have a look for yourself, with the [Osmium Tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/): you can inspect the PBF file and see if the 'name:en' tag is present for the features you are interested in. Use [tag filtering](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#filtering-by-tags)

```
osmium tags-filter rome.osm.pbf n/name \
    -o names-in-rome.osm.pbf
```

It is likely that the OpenStreetMap (OSM) data you are using does not contain English names for all the features you are interested in. OSM data is contributed by volunteers, and the availability of English names for certain features might be inconsistent, especially in non-English speaking regions.

You should consider falling to the default 'name' tag: In your styles.json file, you can use a fallback mechanism to display the default 'name' tag if the 'name:en' tag is not available. You can do this using the `["coalesce", ["get", "name:en"], ["get", "name"]]` expression in your `text-field` property:

```json
{
  "layout": {
    "text-field": ["coalesce", ["get", "name:en"], ["get", "name"]]
  }
}
```

This way, if the 'name:en' tag is missing, the default 'name' tag will be used instead.
See [`coalesce` use here as an example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fallback-image/).